# Getting a -1 from open on iOS, why?

Tags: ios, iphone, file-io, posix, file-descriptor

The code is copied below. I am using the documents directory because I know you can write outside of your apps sandbox.
I also compare the string I was using to determine the path to one created by the NSFileManager and they are the same. What do you all think?

```
- (NSString *)documentsDirectory
{
    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}

- (void) whateverFunction{
    NSString *memfileName = @"memmapfile.map";

    NSString *filePath = [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:memfileName];

    NSLog(@"Here is the filePath: %@", filePath);

    NSLog(@"Other        version: %s", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileSystemRepresentationWithPath:filePath]);
    int memFD = open([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], O_RDWR);
    NSLog(@"I am getting -1 for memFD: %d", memFD);
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your `open()` method? Also, any reason why you're not using Obj-C methods for this?

Comment: First guess would be that your file path is invalid, or you're not authorized to access there.

Comment: The open method is the one from POSIX. I'm using it because I'm trying to do something mmap.

To Hot Licks, I checked errno and get a value of 2 which mapped to the string "No Such Process". What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess your file doesn't exist yet, so of course you can't open it. You should add O_CREAT to your open flags so that it gets created if it doesn't exist:

```
int memFD = open([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Silly oversight.